# Execute macro when clicked on hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, macros

I have a worksheet where each row of the data table has a formula based hyperlink. I want those hyperlinks to execute a macro every time one of those is clicked. The macro needs to a parameter to act differently depending on which row's hyperlink is clicked, so for that I am using active cell's row number.

I have tried various ways I found but none of them complete the functionality. In most cases I need to specify the cell address in the event macro itself which is not a scalable option.

Sample Data:

```
Col A  Col B
A      Link: A
B      Link: B
C      Link: C
D      Link: D
E      Link: E
```

The second column in the above table should be a list of hyperlinks.

The hyperlink formula I am using in the second column (e.g. in cell B1):

```
=HYPERLINK(MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename")),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))-FIND("[",CELL("filename"))+1)&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1),"Link: "&$A1)
```

The macro I am using in the worksheet code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim sData As String
    sData = "text: " & sData & Range(Target.Range.Address). _
    Offset(0, -1).Value & vbCr
    MsgBox sData
End Sub
```

For me in this case, the above macro is not even running when I click on the hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2013 - the method 'signature' for the `Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink` has an additional argument to your event handler. Can you include the `ByVal Sh As Object` in your code and try again:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
  'your code goes here
End Sub
```

Comment: still doesn't work. i tried with just msgbox line in the sub but looks like the clicking on link is not activating the msgbox also

Comment: the hyperlink is targeted at the corresponding cell in the left column. Actually I don't care about the hyperlink but just want to execute a macro when the cell is clicked by mouse, therefore the hyperlink can point to anywhere. I already have a macro that runs when the cell is selected.